# Iterate through photo library on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, photo, photosframework, media-library

I'm trying to iterate through a user's photo library on OS X.  On iOS, I would use the Photos framework, but apparently [that's not available on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144547/programmatic-access-to-the-photos-library-on-mac-os-x-photokit-photos-framewo), and we're supposed to use the Media Library framework instead.  However, while I was able to use the code linked above to get access to a `MLMediaSource` object, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to iterate through the photo assets.

The [Media Library Framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MediaLibrary/Reference/MLMediaSourceClassReference/) makes reference to a `mediaObjectForIdentifier:` method, which sounds promising, but doesn't indicate what sort of identifiers should be used.  I'm fairly experienced with iOS, but a complete n00b on OS X, so I'm feeling a little lost.

If I just wanted to iterate through a user's library, NSLog'ing each photo, how might I go about that?  Either using the Media Library Framework, or another framework so long as it works for the current Photos library?

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with this framework, but decided to just spent 15 mins or so digging through the docs thinking "this must be so simple to do, he's clearly missed something" ... And I couldn't find a thing. Possibly the least friendly library I've ever seen. Sounds silly, but have you tried inputting the image names for the `identifier`? So for Photos, you'd want to try `IMG_number.JPG`.

Comment: @originaluser2  Hahaha thanks.  :)  And I haven't tried that, but are images necessarily named according to that pattern?  I know photos taken on an iPhone are, but what if a user has photos from a camera in the Photos library?

Comment: that's true... just tested it and they're not necessarily renamed on import... So I don't know what suggest!

Comment: Here is it http://stackoverflow.com/a/34929544/436694 . My answer on similar question.

Comment: @Nerrolken I am doing the same thing, can you remember if you are using this MediaLibrary.framework in a sandboxed app, or a normal / wild one? I am going to include it in a wild app but not sure if there is a limitation? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This framework isn't hard to work with, but it is tedious because it async/lazy loads the properties, and KVO is the only want to be notified about the async completion.

If you want to iterate the photos, you don't need to know the identifiers in advance.

Create a media library:

`self.library = [[MLMediaLibrary alloc] initWithOptions:options];`

Add a KVO observer for `mediaSources`. Access mediaSources, if non-nil, go to the next step, otherwise go to the next step when your KVO observer fires.

In the next step, iterate the sources, add a KVO observer on `rootMediaGroup`, and access `rootMediaGroup` on each source. If it is non-nil, call your iterator now, otherwise call it from the KVO notification handler.

For each rootMediaGroup, follow the same strategy as above, but for `mediaObjects`. The media objects are the things you are ultimately after.