# Get GPS location from MLMediaObject on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, gps, photos, media-library

I'm getting started with the [Media Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MediaLibrary/Reference/MLMediaSourceClassReference/) on OS X, specifically with regard to accessing a user's Photos library.  After [a lot of wrangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835821/iterate-through-photo-library-on-os-x/34929677#34929677) I was able to get access to each photo as a MLMediaObject, but now I've hit a roadblock:

**How can I access the GPS location of the photo, from the MLMediaObject?**

This sort of information is easy to get from the old ALAssetsLibrary system, or from the Photos Framework on iOS, using a CLLocation property associated with the media object, but I can't seem to figure it out with the Media Library Framework.  The documentation lists these as the only properties of the MLMediaObject:

```
attributes
mediaType
contentType
name
URL
originalURL
fileSize
modificationDate
thumbnailURL
artworkImage
```

At first I thought `attributes` looked promising, but as far as I can tell there are a [very small number of options](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MediaLibrary/Reference/MediaLibraryConstantsReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012970-CH1-SW126) for that property, and none of them are related to the location.

Then I thought, if I have the file's URL, I ought to be able to get the GPS info directly from the file, but that is proving much more difficult than I expected.

Is there an established means of getting the CLLocation, or other form of GPS data, from a photo using the MLMediaObject? Or if not, can anyone think of a more roundabout way of getting access to that information, starting from an MLMediaObject?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have keys latitude and longitude in attributes. So I assume that it's GPS location of the photo.