# Iterate through photo library on OS X using MLMediaLibrary

Tags: macos, photo, photosframework, media-library

I need to iterate through all albums/photos from the photos app, to get their name,id, directory, thumbnail url.

This question has been asked already at
[Iterate through photo library on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835821/iterate-through-photo-library-on-os-x/34938498#34938498)

but I still cannot get it to work. Based on the code from toohtik at
[Programmatic access to the Photos Library on Mac OS X: PhotoKit / Photos Framework for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144547/programmatic-access-to-the-photos-library-on-mac-os-x-photokit-photos-framewo/34929544#34929544)

I am getting compile error with

```
forKeyPath:@keypath(album, mediaObjects)
```

unexpected @ in code. So if you could tell me what that keypath is, or what I need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make that keypath a thing, in the project
https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc
I downloaded it and took 2 files : EXTKeyPathCoding.h and metamacros.h and included them in my project. Turning @keypath to a macro. And now everything seems to be working.