# How can I observe the UserDefaults data in swift without RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I want to observe defaults for that particulate key whenever I set a new value to that particular key then I want to perform a certain operation where I am observing the change.

```
//Global Variable 

var defaults =  UserDefaults()

//Set the value

self.defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.random.mugish")!
defaults.set("tempValueSet", forKey: "group.random.mugish")

//Read the value


let defaults2 = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.random.mugish")
let x = defaults2?.string(forKey: "group.random.mugish")
```

Comment: KVO is not supported in swift. Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175626/adding-observer-for-kvo-without-pointers-using-swift/32701309#32701309

Comment: @Lirik I believe, The answers to the question you have introduced are no longer working.